# Why adding after() text each time twice on click using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few questions, when i click on particular question `Add Answer` button display. After display button i click on button to get answer according to question which i already clicked using `jQuery after()` like given below:-

It is working but not properly

when i click on first question than click on button, it is give one answer, it is ok

but when i click on second question than click on button is give answer two time, it is not ok

I want just single answer for each question, how can i do that?

```js
$(function(){
  $('button').hide();
  $('.questions').click(function(){
    $('button').show();
    var $QuestionClick = $(this);

  $('button').click(function(){
    $QuestionClick.after('<p>This is text</p>')
  });
  
  });
});
```

```css
.questions{ background:#f1f1f1; border:#ccc; padding:10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Add Answer</button>


<p class="questions">Question 1</p>
<p class="questions">Question 2</p>
```

Answer will be appreciated!

Comment: **Recommend** I think it's more pretty if you wrap your question with a `div` and instead of `insertAfter` use `append`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path, you just need to move you button click function out of the other click function.

```
$(function() {
  $('button').hide();
  var $QuestionClick
  $('.questions').click(function() {
    $('button').show();
    $QuestionClick = $(this);
  });
  $('button').click(function() {
    $QuestionClick.after('<p>This is text</p>')
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').hide();
  var $QuestionClick
  $('.questions').click(function() {
    $('button').show();
    $QuestionClick = $(this);
  });
  $('button').click(function() {
    $QuestionClick.after('<p>This is text</p>')
  });
});
```

```css
.questions {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Add Answer</button>


<p class="questions">Question 1</p>
<p class="questions">Question 2</p>
```